# How to speed up pandas saving data frame to csv?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, csv

Is there any way to speed up the saving process. I have a data frame containing a mere 600,000 rows, and my program got stuck saving the file for ~8 hours before I just quit the program out of frustration. Pandas will successfully save a data frame of 50,000 rows in just 45 seconds, but for some reason this somewhat large data frame is tripping it up. I know that it for sure is the pandas to_csv command that is slowing up the program. Here is some code:
df.to_csv(mes_csv + "_copy.csv.gz", chunksize=100000, header=True, compression='gzip', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This is very weird. Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: This might be because you are using compression. It could take some time to compress the data. Can you try saving without compression and see if the time is reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

You might also try the feather or parquet formats.  Rationale:  speed to save and reload files, and compression (for parquet).

```
df.to_feather('test.feather')

df.to_parquet('test.hd5')
```

Docs are here:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#feather
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#parquet